# phusion passenger on ubuntu 10.04: why apache2-prefork-dev when we want apache2-mpm-worker?

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, passenger

i want to install phusion passenger together with ruby enterprise edition on x86_64 SMP ubuntu 10.04. the recommended option seems to be

```
apache2-mpm-worker
```

but when i run passenger-install-apache2-module

the installation routine of phusion passenger complains

> To install Apache 2 development
>   headers:    Please run apt-get install
>   apache2-prefork-dev as root.

why do we need prefork-dev here, if we clearly want to run passenger with mpm-worker apache2?
any suggestions? is there a worker-dev package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worker dev package on Debian & Ubuntu is "apache2-threaded-dev".

Apt-file shows that this installs /usr/bin/apxs2 among other things, so I think this is what you're looking for.  By the way, I found this package by using "apt-cache search apache mpm dev".

Comment: thanks for your comment - i also read this thread you pointed to, but this is not my problem. i need to know how to install phusion passenger with mpm-worker, or more specific: will phusion passenger be installed with the optimum worker support if i install with the requested apache2-prefork-dev? also i did not find a worker-dev package on ubuntu...

Comment: I updated the answer with some more information.  Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/msg/b7b2dd8a6561ae36

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this, but could you please provide a little description about what may be found at the link you posted to combat link rot? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: That post answers one of the questions ("why do we need prefork-dev here"): it doesn't, prefork-dev just happens to be the default dependency because PHP users need prefork. You are free to install worker if you prefer that instead.